# FPDF return me text instead of PDF File 

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf

I use FPDF to generate some PDF from a PHP. It worked great for small exemple but now i got a problem with it : it return some data which i saw in the console but no file !

ouput look likes - it's the PDF no ?

```
%PDF-1.4
 0 obj
<</Type /Page
/Parent 1 0 R
/Resources 2 0 R
/Group <</Type /Group /S /Transparency /CS /DeviceRGB>>
......
<<
/Size 15
/Root 14 0 R
/Info 13 0 R
>>
startxref
22291
%%EOF
```

And my php is pretty long, here is a pastebin of it http://pastebin.com/ri5uAeie

My php looks correct, really weird no ?

## UPDATE

I pass my param throw the URL and with a $_GET and it works well :) Thanks for your help guys !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've probably added a blank line somewhere, possibly at `inc/DataLib.php`.

**Update #1:**

According to your answers, there's two suspicious points:

1. The `Content-Type` should be `application/pdf`. In theory, the [PDF::Output()](http://fpdf.org/en/doc/output.htm) method adds it for you (unless `php_sapi_name()` returns `cli`, which should not be possible in web environment).
2. Getting a blank page in a desktop PDF reader (rather than an error) suggests that the document is damaged in a way that the reader cannot even detect it... or that the document is actually blank.

No idea about #1 (firewall? proxy? antivirus?) but you could at least inspect the PDF source in search of PHP error messages or something that does not belong there.

**Update #2:**

I think I finally understood what your problem is. You cannot use JavaScript to retrieve a PDF file though AJAX. All JavaScript can do is:

1. Manipulate the page's DOM (and PDF is not HTML).
2. Replace the complete DOM page with something else (and there's no way to tell the browser what content-type it is).

I suspect your PDF generator is just fine if you call it directly from the location bar.

Comment: nah, blank line returns error. I got no errors here :) THx for helping btw !

Comment: Alright.... Basic questions are: 1) What's the generated `Content-Type` header()? 2) Do you have a working PDF plug-in in your browser? 3) Does the file render if you save it to disk and open it manually with your PDF reader?

Comment: 1) the contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' - in a Jquery POST
2) Yep, I use Chromium. I made FPDF works days ago... 
3) i can open it but it's blank

I also try to open my php in another tab but that was no better..

Comment: well, if i put the content-type to application/pdf the POST don't works anymore... 
I use Jquery to post data from JS to PHP ... http://pastebin.com/V6Ar2JMB

I'll check for PHP mistake...

Comment: Feel free to update the question and add details there. Code in comments is unreadable. Whatever, I suggest you fix problems one by one. Make sure you can generate a PDF properly before attempting AJAX stuff.

Answer (score 0):

That's how calling `FPDF::Output()` with no arguments work. It just sets appropriate headers and sends PDF as text to browser. If you want the file to be downloaded, you need to provide `Output()` with filename and set second argument to `'D'`

Comment: well i already try with
    $pdf->Output('test.pdf','D');

But it's the same output ...